# Google Maps Place Picker iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

I am implementing the google maps place picker in Swift. The place picker provided by google automatically displays a view controller with a navigation bar. When I select the location or press the back button on the navigation bar, the view controller immediately disappears without any transition. I cannot seem to access the navigation bar at all through the place picker API. How could I dismiss the placepicker view controller with an animation, or perhaps access the navigation bar? I am at a loss. My code brings up the place picker when I press a button:

```
    @IBAction func pickPlace(sender: UIButton) {
    if let mapView = self.mapView {

        let visibleRegion = mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
        let viewport = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: visibleRegion.farLeft, coordinate: visibleRegion.nearRight)
        let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: viewport)
        placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)
        placePicker.pickPlaceWithCallback { (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println("Error picking place: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            if place != nil {
                self.userLocationTextField.text = place!.name
                println("Place name \(place!.name)")
                println("Place address \(place!.formattedAddress)")
                println("Place attributions \(place!.attributions)")


                let marker = GMSMarker(position: place!.coordinate)
            } else {
                println("No place selected")
            }
        }
    }
```

The only way I can get access to the place picker view controller is with the following code:

```
    let topVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
```

But even with that code, I cannot make change the navigation bar or make the view controller dismiss with animation.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you ever manage to get this fixed?

Comment: I was never able to fix it, unfortunately

Comment: i have the same problem. did you found any solution for the navigation issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and I have solved using below code.
I have written below code in place picker button action method

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = YOURCOLOR
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```